Gradient in navigation bar together with scrollable content
I discovered that one can put gradient backgrounds in the navigation bar in SwiftUI - if the first element is a VStack and you put a background on the first element, for whatever reason this gradient also expands over into the navigation bar.
I am using this to create a cover-like View on top of scrollable content together with the standard navigation bar:

struct ContentView: View {

    static let gradient = RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [.init(color: .red, location: 0), .init(color: .yellow, location: 1)]), center: .bottom, startRadius: 0, endRadius: 300)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "lasso.badge.sparkles")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 120))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Self.gradient)
            
                Form {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { idx in
                        Text("Hello, world! \(idx)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Foo", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to move the image (the lasso.badge.sparkles in the example) into the scrollable content (into the Form / could also be a ScrollView) so that it scrolls under the standard navigation bar (which then should do its default-material-background-blur thing), but keep the continuous gradient in the initial non-scrolled state? Something like this when scrolled down:


If you can live with grouped list style, then moving the gradient to the header of a list section is one way of getting it to work:

Nest the main content of the List inside a Section.
Show the gradient in the section header.
Move .ignoresSafeArea() to the List.
Surround the List with a GeometryReader. This makes it possible to find the size of the safe area insets.
Add top padding to the header, to allow for the top safe area inset.

NavigationStack {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        List {
            Section {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { idx in
                    Text("Hello, world! \(idx)")
                }
            } header: {
                Image(systemName: "lasso.badge.sparkles")
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 120))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(
                        Self.gradient
                    )
                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationBarTitle("Foo", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}



Alternatively, one way of keeping the insetGrouped list style is to surround the VStack in your original example with a ScrollView. This means the scroll view will contain content that is itself scrollable, so the following adaptions are needed:

Disable scrolling on the List. This way, all scrolling is performed by the ScrollView.
Set a fixed height on the List to fit the contents.
Handle the safe area insets as before.

Computing the height for the List may be difficult. However, you could consider setting a defaultMinListRowHeight on the List and then computing the overall height using the same value, based on the number of rows. A ScaledMetric could also be used to detect an increase to the dynamic font size.
Here is how the example could be updated to use this approach:
@ScaledMetric private var defaultMinListRowHeight: CGFloat = 44

private var minRowHeight: CGFloat {
    max(defaultMinListRowHeight, 44)
}

NavigationStack {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "lasso.badge.sparkles")
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 120))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(
                        Self.gradient
                    )
                List {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { idx in
                        Text("Hello, world! \(idx)")
                    }
                }
                .scrollDisabled(true)
                .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, minRowHeight)
                .frame(height: (101 * minRowHeight) + 50, alignment: .top)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationBarTitle("Foo", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}



Thanks for looking into this and your input on this! I'd like to focus on building the upper "cover image with gradient" part and skip the problem of using a Form/List inside a ScrollView as I am ok with building the content below the gradient cover image without Form/List in a plain ScrollView. Your first solution is interesting. Unfortunately, .ignoresSafeArea() on a List breaks the scroll indicators which need to take the safe area into account. But one can sneak in just the upper part of the gradient with .ignoresSafeArea() and this seems to do the trick. Posted an example as 2nd answer.

@RalfEbert Hope you're closer to finding a solution. If the answer helped, you are welcome to give it an upvote ;)

Based on Benzy's idea of using GeometryReader and geometry.safeAreaInsets.top to get the nav bar height, I found I can sneak in just the upper part of the gradient with .ignoresSafeArea() and this seems to do the trick:
struct ContentView: View {

    static let gradient = RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [.init(color: .red, location: 0), .init(color: .yellow, location: 1)]), center: .bottom, startRadius: 0, endRadius: 300)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    Image(systemName: "lasso.badge.sparkles")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 120))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 220)
                        .background {
                            Self.gradient
                        }
                    Text("...")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Foo", displayMode: .inline)
                .background(alignment: .top) {
                    Self.gradient
                        .frame(height: 220 + geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
                        .clipped()
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

(this example assumes the cover image with the gradient has a fixed height and ignores the problem of using a List/Form below the cover image)
